# When the validated input value changes from valid to invalid the removeClass call won't fire

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery Validate Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) on my postcode form.

I've got it setup so that it returns a `<label>` with the class `.error` or `.valid` depending on validation. If the `<input>` validates, a hidden `<a>` is revealed to show a contact number.

It works fine unless the user enters an invalid postcode *after* entering a valid one. If they do that the valid message is replaced with the invalid one, as desired. But the contact number `<a>` tag remains visible.

**Here's the code:**

```
  //js
  $('.postcode_form').validate({
    rules: {
      postcode: {
        required: true,
        range: [3030, 3340]
      }
    },
    messages: {
      postcode: {
        range: "Sorry, doesn't look like we service that area"
      }
    },
    onkeyup: false,

    success: function (label) {
      var callNow = ".call-now";
      label.addClass("valid").text("Looks good, call us now");
      if(label.hasClass("valid")) {
        $(callNow).addClass('is-visible');
      }
    }
  });

  //html
  <form class="postcode_form" id="postcode_form" name="postcode_form" action="#">
    <input type="number" id="your_postcode" class="your_postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="3???">
    <button type="button" class="area-btn"><span></span></button>
    <a href="tel:+6#########" class="call-now">##########</a>
  </form>
```

As I said everything works great except if they enter an invalid postcode after having already submitted a valid one. I know it's not likely they'll do that but for those occasions when it does happen I'd like to fix it.

I had an `else` clause in the `success: function` like so,

```
  success: function (label) {
    var callNow = ".call-now";
    label.addClass("valid").text("Looks good, call us now");
    if(label.hasClass("valid")) {
      $(callNow).addClass('is-visible');
    } else {
      $(callNow).removeClass('is-visible');
    }
  }
```

But it appears to have had no effect. I don't think it was even getting read.

I'm leaning towards `label.addClass("valid").text("Looks good, call us now");` as being the culprit. It's like as soon as a valid `<label>` is built it won't recognise the `removeClass` call. Even though the whole validation process is still happening.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

> When the validated input value changes from valid to invalid the removeClass call won't fire

There's nothing wrong with `removeClass` or anything else within your `success` callback function.  The problem is, by definition, the `success` callback itself is never going to fire when the element is "invalid"...

The intended purpose of the `success` callback option is to control the error message `label` **only when an input is "valid"**.  Since `success` ***only*** fires when the element is "valid" your if/else is not going to work since you're erroneously expecting `success` to also fire when the element changes to "invalid".

Try the `highlight` and `unhighlight` options instead to control the classes.  These will fire whenever the validity of any given field toggles back and forth.  (The message itself will automatically toggle since the same `label` element is used both when the input is "valid" and "invalid".)

Basically, use `success` to manipulate your `label` whenever "valid", and `highlight-unhighlight` to toggle classes when "invalid"-"valid" respectively.

```
success: function(label) {
    label.addClass("valid").text("Looks good, call us now");
},
highlight: function(element) {
    $('.call-now').removeClass('is-visible');
},
unhighlight: function(element) {
    $('.call-now').addClass('is-visible');
},
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/k7t5ko83/**

Comment: Thanks @Sparky . I'd actually implemented the `highlight` `unhighlight` options before. The problem was I also left the `if` statement in the `success` option, so I guess it was overriding them. Story of my life `close but no cigar. lol. Thanks again, know I can finally put this form behind me.